# Angular: how to update an open dialog data from background?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The thing is with a click of a button I am starting a service in the background and launching the dialog both at the same time. Now I want to update the dialog with the return of the service, without recalling open dialog to pass the message.

My code to open and send:

```
 dialogLoading(title,subTitle, imgid) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogLoadingComponent, {
      width: 'auto',
      data: {title: title, subTitle : subTitle, imgID : imgid},
      disableClose: true,
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
```

How to update the title and other elements without closing the dialog?

Comment: If this is matDialog I’m not sure, but I can imagine you can still update data using the dialogRef maybe? So this.dialogRef.data.Title = “updated title”..?

Comment: You can pass an "object" to your DialogLoadingComponent and to your service and change some property of the object, or your DialogLoadingComponent can subscribe in ngOnInit to a Subject and the service emit a change

Answer (score 1):

Consider using another service say *UpdateDialogueContentsService*.

Inject the service both on the component calling the Dialogue and also on the dialogue component

Declare the properties that you need to be updated on the service as observables and then subscribe to those observables on the dialogue component

In your *UpdateDialogueContentsService*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UpdateDialogueContentsService {
  titleChange$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Old Title')
  title$ = this.titleChange$.asObservable();
  constructor() { }
}
```

In your Dialogue component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UpdateDialogueContentsService } from '../update-dialogue-contents.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-dialogue',
  templateUrl: './my-dialogue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-dialogue.component.css']
})
export class MyDialogueComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    private dialogueUpdateService: UpdateDialogueContentsService
  ) { }

  title$ = this.dialogueUpdateService.title$;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

In the Component calling the openDialog() include

```
constructor(
  private dialogueUpdateService: UpdateDialogueContentsService,
  ...
)
updateTitle() {
  this.dialogueUpdateService.titleChange$.next('NEW TITLE!!')
}
```

Finally in your dialog component html file, just include the value

```
<h1>{{ title$ | async }}</h1>
```

Note: We are subscribing using the *async* pipe hence no need to unsubscribe

See Below [Implementation on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lk4sbw)